# Brute forcing the twosum algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

The twosum question is:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9, Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9, return [0, 1].

I'm learning java and I'm going through some leetcode problems. I'm trying to come up with a brute force solution before I code for efficiency but my code won't seem to compile:

```
public class TwoSum 
{
//static int[] arraynums = new int[]{2, 7, 11, 15};
//static int target = 9;

//public static void main(String args[])
//{
    //TwoSum name = new TwoSum();
    //name.twoSums(arraynums, target);
//}
    public int twoSums(int[] nums, int target) 
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++)
            {   
                sum = nums[i] + nums[j];
                if (sum == target)
                {
                    System.out.println(i + " " + j);
                    return new int[] {i,j};
                }

            }
        }
        return new int[] {};
    }
}
```

I know I need a return statement but I'm not sure what I should return and I'm also not sure if my main method is required.

Comment: When you write `public int[] twoSum(...`, you are saying that your method twoSum(...) will return an array of int elements. It seems you want to do something else instead. Check your basics on method definition.

Answer (score 0):

For leetCode you just need to complete the codes and no need to add a main function.

For your **twoSum** method you need to return an **array** with type **int** which contains the index of elements.

You can test like this:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] testData = {2, 7, 11, 15};
    int target = 9;
    TwoSum ts = new TwoSum();
    int[] result = ts.twoSum(testData, target);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm also doing that for myself (so I can fully understand how Java is used)

Comment: Yes it's very usefull to print things out so you can check your logic.

Answer (score 0):

@Alfabravo is right. you need to return an array of integer. If you don't want to return anything. just use

```
 public void twoSum(int[] nums, int target)
```

Comment: it will also run that way. Also in main method just instantiate the class like this.

Comment: TwoSum name = new TwoSum(); 

        name.twoSum("arraynums", "target");

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track!

In regards to adding a `return` statement, just add it after the println statement.

```
...
System.out.println(i + " " + j);
return new int[] {i,j};
...
```

although you need to check that `i` and `j` are not equal as they will point to the same number in `nums` if they are. *Unless* that isn't a requirement of the question. If it is you could add something like

```
if (sum == target && i != j)
```

good luck.

Comment: When I add this return statement, I still get an error that I'm missing a return statement :(

Comment: its because not all code paths return a value. add `return false` at the very end of the function and it should work.

Comment: Hmmm

TwoSum.java:19: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
            return new int[] {i,j};
                   ^
TwoSum.java:24: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
         return false;
                ^

Comment: sorry not `return false` (what was I thinking) you should return the specified return type which in your case in an `int` array - which would be `return new int[] {}; (an empty array because there were no two sums.

Comment: I see where you are going with this but still getting errors

TwoSum.java:23: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
            return new int[] {i,j};
                   ^
TwoSum.java:28: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
         return new int[] {};
                ^

Comment: did you by change change your function to `void`?

Comment: I went ahead and edited my code so you can see what I did

Comment: Now your return type is `int`. unless you return an int its gonna throw an error. either change `int` to `int[]` or change the return statements to return ints.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] num, int target) {
    // Take an array and the target number as parameter
    // Initialize the variables
        int length = num.length;
        int index1 = 0;
        int index2 = 0;
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
        // First loop, i starts at num[0] which is the first element in array
            for (j=i+1; j<length; j++){
            // Second loop, j starts at num[1], the second element
                if (num[i] + num[j] == target){
                // If they are equal return the index
                    index1 = i;
                    index2 = j;
                }
            }
        }
        // The result should be an array contains 2 indices
        int[] result = new int[] {index1, index2};
        return result;
    }
}
```

Loop through each element x and find if there is another value that equals to target−x.

Comment: Can you please post a description on how the code works

Answer (score 0):

Just a small mistake when you're iterating in the next loop, just add j = i + 1. That will do it.

```
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++){
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                return new int[] { i,j };
            }
        }
    }
    return new int[] {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    
    public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        int first = 0, sec = numbers.length-1;
        while(first!=sec){
            if((numbers[first]+numbers[sec])==target)
                break;
            else if((numbers[first]+numbers[sec])>target)
                sec--;
            else
                first++;
        }
        int res[] = new int[2];
        res[0] = first+1;
        res[1] = sec+1;
        
        return res;
    }
}
```